# Multiple Databases, or Tables with large content

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I was going to post this on Database Administrators, but as it is slightly related to PHP, I felt it would be better to post here.

I have a website that currently uses 8 databases, with tables within these databases that all link back to a particular table in the primary database (if that makes sense). I am aware that this is pretty poor design, everything I know is self-taught, so my knowledge with database design is pretty limited. ***The reason for me originally designing the databases like this is because the content within them will be increasing exponentially. I therefore felt that I should spread the load into separate tables, but I couldn't do this without having separate databases (for complex reasons).***

Currently, for each PHP script that I run, I initiate 8 connections to my MySQL Server, one for each database. I know this is bad!!!

My colleague has suggested a complete redesign that uses just one database and a few tables, but with a lot more fields and a lot more content. My question is, quite simply, is he right? Should I try and combine all my databases into one and have as few tables as possible, even if the data is going to be pretty large? ***The argument he puts forward, is that databases are designed to hold large amounts of data whether it be 10 million or 10 billion records. This is their job, so I should just trust them and design the database in a way that works easiest for me.***

I have read through the following Stackoverflow questions but I think my question is slightly different for the reason that the database is likely to have an extremely large amount of content and therefore the answer may be different. Apologies if not!

1. [Large websites - multiple databases or or multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866557/multiple-databases-tables-or-combined-into-one)
2. [Multiple databases tables or combined into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866557/multiple-databases-tables-or-combined-into-one)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much content do you exactly have?

Comment: At the moment, not much at all, but if the website hits off then the content will eventually be huge and I want to design for that to make my job easier in the long run

Comment: So you're scaling prematurely and your friend was right with his advice. Listen to him and optimize for scale when you exhaust all available options (such as running your site on an extremely powerful server).

Comment: No, it's not sarcasm. You really are optimizing prematurely. Also, scaling the way you imagined isn't done like that. Sure, you have 8 database servers. But what about http server? Only one?

Comment: I apologize, I read your comment wrong. :-) No, I have 8 databases, one MySQL Server and one HTTP server. I will of course scale onto higher power servers, if, need be in the future. But I want to make sure the design of the database is right and will work well if the situation does present itself

Comment: Well, if you have those databases on 1 physical computer, it's not relevant whether you have 1 or 8. They use resources of a single computer. Your attempt to optimize actually downgraded the performance, if we talk larger amount of concurrent users. Also, how are you syncing those databases? What info do they hold? Is it any sort of data that's bound to do calculations or joins? There are numerous questions like these and yes, I'll repeat - your colleague   was right.

Comment: As long as the db user has privileges on all 8 databases, you don't need 8 connections, you just specify the database name before the table name.

Comment: @Darhazer, well aware of that, I have separate users for each database. N.B. The queries are ridiculously simple, just basic Selects with the occasional join, no calculations or complex functions. No stored procedures. I am definitely going to go with what my colleague has suggested, as quite obviously, it is the right design. Thank you all for your kind help, hopefully I will be able to get this done without any hassle. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, quite simply, is he right?

Yes, you need to keep your database hits as low as possible, not to increase it. If you have only one user, you open 8 connections. If you have two, you suddenly need 16! Three - 24!! How  you came to conclusion, that this would spread the load? In my opinion it actually does the opposite, not mentioning problems with relational data and the design of the application itself.

So, some basic rules:

**database** - one application -> one database (unless really necessary and you need to know WHY and HOW to do that)

**tables**, **columns** - depends on the data you need to store, but generally you want to make it simple, flexible and easy to maintain over time, especially if it is a huge website (or plan to be).

If you'd have a query, that needs to select the data from multiple tables, you wouldn't write multiple queries either, right? You'd write one query with "joins" to do only one database hit, and it's basically the same principle with having multiple databases...

Comment: And if you need to spread the load over multiple servers, that is what clustering is for. But you still use only one database.

Comment: That is very helpful thank you. I am aware that my current design is dreadful, it is hard to explain why and how I came about choosing it but it all really boils down to the fact that I have never been taught how to design a database. I just teach myself by trial and error, along with the kind help of people like you! :-)